# How to move tabs to beneath the app title

Tags: flutter, dart

Im creating a page which has a few tabs to sort food into categories. For some reason theres a large white section between the top app bar where the title is and the actual tabs. I want to move the tabs up so they're below the app bar and there is not a large white space there! Does anyone know how or why this is the case? Thank you!

I am using flutter.

[image]

```
class FoodPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodPageState createState() => _FoodPageState();
}


class _FoodPageState extends State<FoodPage> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        //primarySwatch: Colors.teal,

      ),
      home:DefaultTabController(
        length:4,
        child:  Scaffold(
        backgroundColor:Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),

          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5,
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: -30,right: -30),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10),topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
              ),

              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10),topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('ALL'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                 Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10),topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('FRIDGE'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10),topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('FREEZER'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10),topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('CUPBOARD'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
            
            Text('ALL FOOD HERE'),
            Text('FRIDGE FOOD HERE'),
            Text('FREEZER FOOD HERE'),
            Text('CUPBOARD FOOD HERE')
          ]),
        )
      )
    ) ;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can adjust tabbar height by changing below parameter.

**toolbarHeight**

[image]

```
...
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 50,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5,
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
...
```

Comment: Thank you @KuKu! I have adjusted it so toolbarheight is set to 0 and it is a lot better, however theres still a bit of a gap between my Appbar at the top and my tabs. Do you have any idea why this may be? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is what it looks like after having added the toolbarheight:0 ,[link](https://ibb.co/fHTntvq)